# KSH: How to add Date Time at the end of a New File e.g. FileMMDDYYYYHHMM

Tags: ksh

I am having a requirement where I want the output as

```
FileMMDDYYYYHHMM
```

I tried the following things

I am having a file called abc.ksh in which I have Declared a variable as

```
MYDATETIME=${DATE}${TIME}
```

and I am passing the parameter as

```
cp $MY_DATA_DIR/My_Reports $MY_DATA_DIR/My_Reports$MYDATETIME
```

In the above I am getting the OutPut as My_Reports without MYDATETIME

I also used the echo command to Print the out put

```
echo "my datetime" $MYDATETIME
```

I got the Output as

```
my datetime
```

It is not adding the expected date time to File `[My_Reports]`. 
Am I doing something wrong here? 
Can anyone suggest or guide me on the same.

Comment: is the problem in a different script? This looks ok otherwise, but look carefully for typos in the vars for file2. As is your question can't be diagnosed. It's better to include actual copy/paste of a small subset of your script + output that has the problem. Also turn on `set -x` near the top of your script, maybe the debug output will help you spot where the problem is. Good luck.

Comment: Also, why do you awk in the title, this is clearly a ksh problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks for your valuable inputs. I have edited and changed my question from AWK to KSH.

Comment: Could you post relevant parts of your script? Where are `$DATE` and `$TIME` set?

Comment: Looks like the variable MYDATETIME is not set.  If it is created in a different script then maybe your should "source" the other script first with `. abc.ksh` (note the `.` command).

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, I don't see you initializing your DATETIME variable.  If I was in your shoes, I'd do the following:

```
$MY_DATA_DIR=/this/is/my/derp
MYDATETIME=`date +%m%d%Y%H%M`
cp $MY_DATA_DIR/My_Reports $MY_DATA_DIR/My_Reports$MYDATETIME
```

If you want to split date and time, then:

```
$DATE=`date +%m%d%Y`
$TIME=`date +%H%M`
$MYDATETIME = ${DATE}${TIME}
```

Enjoy!